# Is there a way to import/export - Credit Card Refund, Credit Card Charge, Deposits and Transfers in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

Is there a way to import/export - Credit Card Refund, Credit Card Charge, Deposits and Transfers in NetSuite. (It seems these are not supported CSV import assistant which is evident from SuiteAnswer Id 10008).

It seems it is not supported by CSV Import tool, nor these records are scriptable. As these record types are not visible in [SuiteScript Record Browser](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2015_1/script/record/account.html).

Is there any workaround using SuiteScripts or some other mechanism to import these records into NetSuite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deposits are fully scriptable except cannot be copied.
Deposits and Transfers my be exported via saved searches. 
For the rest if you are trying to import historicals you'd probably have to use Journal Entries. As far as that goes the others should be available for export via the GL as well.

Answer (score 0):

Deposits are fully scriptable as pointed by @bknights. So, I am using the SuiteScript approach to import/export these records.

Transfers can be exported to some extent via saved search but, not fully because some fields like, target account are not exposed in Transaction search column, so, manual data entry is the only option left, otherwise we can write some sort of DOM script(I think this is the best bad option) as it is a one time job.

NetSuite has filled an enhancement #170963 for web services/suitescript support for "Bank Transfer Transactions". Similarly for "Card Refund and Credit Card Charge" their is an enhancement #163940.

The CSV import/export for the same are under enhancement as per case#2303685.